# WebDriver firefox нажать на checkbox c#

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Добрый день, нужно кликнуть по `checkbox`, сам `checkbox` имеет такой код

```
<span class="popup__checkbox-mask"></span>
<div class="popup__rules-desc has-error">
                <label class="popup__label" for="registration_accept_terms">
                    <input id="registration_accept_terms" name="registration[accept_terms]" required="required" class="popup__input--checkbox" data-error="checked" value="2" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="popup__checkbox-mask"></span>
                    <span class="popup__label-text">Вы подтверждаете свое согласие с <a class="popup__rules-link" href="/rules" target="_blank">правилами клуба</a></span>
                </label>
                                    <div class="popup__error">Подтвердите, пожалуйста, что вы согласны с правилами клуба</div>
                            </div>
```

Пытался так :

```
var ceck= driver.FindElement(By.Id("registration_accept_terms"));
            ceck.Click() ;
```

Но на клике дает ошибку (`OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException" in WebDriver.dll`). Как-то можно через xpath, но я чет не смог разобраться, можете подсказать ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
var check = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("type=checkbox"));
```